# Template prop in my grid not working (Syncfusion)

Tags: c#, .net, syncfusion

I use a syncfusion grid in my app & my template value is like this

```
var format = "N" + header.NbDecimals; // value of format is  'N0'

col.Template = "<p class="number">${format(data." + header.val + ")('" + format + "')} " +
header.CurrencyChar + "

";
```

and this my js

```
var columns = {....template: value.Template }  constructColumns.push(columns);
```

when i remove template it's work fine but when i use template i have this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')
```